# Image in canvas leaves a tiled trail when panned

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to create a pannable image viewer which also allows magnification. If the zoom factor or the image size is such that the image no longer paints over the entire canvas then I wish to have the area of the canvas which does not contain the image painted with a specified background color.

My current implementation allows for zooming and panning but with the unwanted effect that the image leaves a tiled trail after it during a pan operation (much like the cards in windows Solitaire when you win a game). How do I clean up my canvas such that the image does not leave a trail and my background rectangle properly renders in my canvas?

To recreate the unwanted effect set magnification to some level at which you see the dark gray background show and then pan the image with the mouse (mouse down and drag).

Code snippet added below and Plnkr link for those who wish to muck about there.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Cl4T4d13AgPpaDFzhsq1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      canvas{
        border:solid 5px #333;
      }
    </style>
    
  </head>

  <body>

   <button onclick="changeScale(0.10)">+</button>
   <button onclick="changeScale(-0.10)">-</button>
   
    <div id="container">
      <canvas width="700" height="500" id ="canvas1"></canvas>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var imageDimensions ={width:0,height:0};
      var photo = new Image();
      var isDown = false;
      var startCoords = [];
      var last = [0, 0];
      var windowWidth = canvas.width;
      var windowHeight = canvas.height;

      var scale=1;
      
      photo.addEventListener('load', eventPhotoLoaded , false);
      photo.src = "http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png";
      
      function eventPhotoLoaded(e) {
        imageDimensions.width = photo.width;
        imageDimensions.height = photo.height;
        drawScreen();
      }
      
      function changeScale(delta){
        scale += delta;
        drawScreen();
      }
      
      function drawScreen(){
        context.fillRect(0,0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        context.fillStyle="#333333";
        context.drawImage(photo,0,0,imageDimensions.width*scale,imageDimensions.height*scale);
      }

      canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
          isDown = true;
      
          startCoords = [
              e.offsetX - last[0],
              e.offsetY - last[1]
         ];
      };
      
      canvas.onmouseup   = function(e) {
          isDown = false;
          
          last = [
              e.offsetX - startCoords[0], // set last coordinates
              e.offsetY - startCoords[1]
          ];
      };
      
      canvas.onmousemove = function(e)
      {
          if(!isDown) return;
          
          var x = e.offsetX;
          var y = e.offsetY;
          
          context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1,
                           x - startCoords[0], y - startCoords[1]);
          drawScreen();
      }
      

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe something like `context.save(); context.fillRect(0,0, windowWidth, windowHeight); context.restore();` Since setTransform also change the rectangle you fill.

Comment: You are correct. If you'd like to develop that comment as an answer I will be glad to accept it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice Code ;)

You are seeing the 'tiled' effect in your demonstration because you are painting the scaled image to the canvas on top of itself each time the `drawScreen()` function is called while dragging. You can rectify this in two simple steps.

First, you need to clear the canvas between calls to `drawScreen()` and second, you need to use the canvas `context.save()` and `context.restore()` methods to cleanly reset the canvas *transform matrix* between calls to `drawScreen()`.

Given your code as is stands:

Create a function to clear the canvas. e.g.

```
  function clearCanvas() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
```

In the `canavs.onmousemove()` function, call `clearCanvas()` and invoke `context.save()` *before* redefining the transform matrix...

```
  canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
      if(!isDown) return;

      var x = e.offsetX;
      var y = e.offsetY;

      /* !!! */
      clearCanvas();
      context.save();

      context.setTransform(
         1, 0, 0, 1,
         x - startCoords[0], y - startCoords[1]
      );

      drawScreen();
  }
```

... then conditionally invoke `context.restore()` at the end of `drawScreen()` ...

```
function drawScreen() {
    context.fillRect(0,0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    context.fillStyle="#333333";
    context.drawImage(photo,0,0,imageDimensions.width*scale,imageDimensions.height*scale);
    /* !!! */
    if (isDown) context.restore();
}
```

Additionally, you may want to call `clearCanvas()` before rescaling the image, and the canvas background could be styled with CSS rather than `.fillRect()` (in `drawScreen()`) - which could give a performance gain on low spec devices.

*Edited in light of comments from **Blindman67** below*

**See Also**

- Canvas.context.save : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save
- Canvas.context.restore : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore
- requestAnimationFrame : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame
- Paul Irish, requestAnimationFrame polyfill : http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Wonderful answer. I can tell you are a deep well on this subject.

Comment: Why use the expensive save/restore step when all that is needed is to reset the transform to the default. And why the `if(context.save) context.restore()` ??? save is a function and will always evaluate as true. You have only added unneeded complexity. Also adding RAF to mouse event is not a good idea as the mouse move can fire many times during a frame. Should be decoupling rendering from mouse events and render only once per refresh all else is a waste of processing as it will never be seen.

Comment: @Blindman67 "save is a function and will always evaluate as true" - Yes, that is sloppy, but some condition needs to apply as `drawScreen()` is also called outside of the `onmousemove` event cycle - e.g `if (isDown) context.restore()`?.  I consider RAF a useful method for throttling calls to the draw function - perhaps you could give a more detailed explanation below. ;)

Comment: @BrianPeacock RAF will call the callback for each time you call RAF. If that is within one screen refresh it will simple do multiple renders befor the canvas is presented to the display. In this case about half the renders will never be seen. Keep the rendering and IO separate. I have updated my answer, though it is subjective as to what is the best method yours had some flaws that would present problems for people new to this. Update your answer if you wish to use save and restore and I will remove mine.

Comment: @Blindman67 I've removed references to `requestAnimationFrame` from my answer.  Keeping 'save' and 'restore' as a minimal addition that makes the original code work without need for a structural overhaul.  Today I learned something important! :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to reset the transform.

Add `context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);` just before you clear the canvas and that will fix your problem. It sets the current transform to the default value. Then befor the image is draw set the transform for the image.

**UPDATE:**
When interacting with user input such as mouse or touch events it should be handled independently of rendering. The rendering will fire only once per frame and make visual changes for any mouse changes that happened during the previous refresh interval. No rendering is done if not needed.

Dont use save and restore if you don't need to.

```js
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var photo = new Image();
      var mouse = {}
      mouse.lastY = mouse.lastX = mouse.y = mouse.x = 0;
      mouse.down = false;
      var changed = true;
      var scale = 1;
      var imageX = 0;
      var imageY = 0;
      photo.src = "http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png";
      function changeScale(delta){
        scale += delta;
        changed = true;
      }
      // Turns mouse button of when moving out to prevent mouse button locking if you have other mouse event handlers.
      function mouseEvents(event){  // do it all in one function
          if(event.type === "mouseup" || event.type === "mouseout"){
            mouse.down = false;
            changed = true;
          }else
          if(event.type === "mousedown"){
            mouse.down = true;            
          }
          mouse.x = event.offsetX;
          mouse.y = event.offsetY;
          if(mouse.down) {
            changed = true;
          }
      }
      canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",mouseEvents);
      canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",mouseEvents);
      canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",mouseEvents);
      canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",mouseEvents);

      function update(){
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
        if(photo.complete && changed){
          ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
          ctx.fillStyle="#333";
          ctx.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          if(mouse.down){
            imageX += mouse.x - mouse.lastX;
            imageY += mouse.y - mouse.lastY;
          }
          ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, imageX,imageY);
          ctx.drawImage(photo,0,0);
          changed = false;
        }
        mouse.lastX = mouse.x
        mouse.lastY = mouse.y                  
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas{
    border:solid 5px #333;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="changeScale(0.10)">+</button><button onclick="changeScale(-0.10)">-</button>
<canvas width="700" height="500" id ="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: Works nicely and solves a problem I was having with the scaling function as well when simply saving and restoring state.

Answer (score 2):

Call `context.save` to save the transformation matrix before you call `context.fillRect`.
Then whenever you need to draw your image, call `context.restore` to restore the matrix.

For example:

```
function drawScreen(){
    context.save();
    context.fillStyle="#333333";
    context.fillRect(0,0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    context.restore();
    context.drawImage(photo,0,0,imageDimensions.width*scale,imageDimensions.height*scale);
  }
```

Also, to further optimize, you only need to set `fillStyle` once until you change the size of canvas.